# JavaFX, problems with setScene()

Tags: java, javafx, scene, stage

I had a bug in my program, so I have made this little example code to illustrate what is going on. What happens is that the first scene doesn't seem to go away, and when I set the scene a second time, the old one keeps on interfering with the new scene. I am not sure why this happens. If you have any suggestions to why this happens, or/and know a workaround, I would be happy to hear and try them.

thanks alot!

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

private Stage window;
private Scene scene1, scene2;
private Button button1, button2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    button1 = new Button("Click me");
    button2 = new Button("Click me 2");

    scene1 = new Scene(button1);
    scene2 = new Scene(button2);

    window = primaryStage;

    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.show();

    button1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene2));
    button2.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(scene1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me. When it shows the first button and I click on it, I see the second button. When I click on the second button I see the first button again. What do you mean by "the old one keeps on interfering with the new scene"?

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. Sorry for my lack of clarity there. I meant that the first scene stays, and is not removed when I try to overwrite it with the new scene. So the two scenes seems to be overlapping for some reason.

Comment: Each scene is completely filled with a button anyway, so I'm not sure what it would look like if they were overlapping. Can you post an image somewhere?

Comment: I am not quite sure where to do that. But I can explain what happens. The first button is clickable, and yes, it does take me to a new scene. However, the button on the new scene is not clickable. And the text expands to cover alot more of the button, and the resolution of the text is very low. I will try to look for a way to post images of it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tkKgChq

It's not pretty, but it shows what the problem is. Remember that the button "click me 2", is not clickable.

Comment: There are two windows there... are there two instances of the application? What platform are you on?

Comment: Just mixed two screenshots. One displays how the button should look, and the second one shows what happens when I click it

Comment: I know it's not very clear. But I have made a workaround. I found that if I resize the window, it will work. So something happens when I click the button in terms of resizing. However, if I force the stage to have a static size, it works perfectly. Thanks alot for you time, James! :)

Comment: try exchanging the root node of the scene instead of the `Scene` itself. For example, create two instances of `Group`. Set the scene once.

Comment: hey, got your same problem. the scene that i override still exist somewhere. how did you solved?